# how to print from an application in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

[image]

I want the user to be able to print the content of this screen with the print button on the screen.
how do I print the content of this screen with the print button on the screen?

Comment: That depends on what type of content(s) you are talking about.

Comment: @ApuCoder I want to print the whole screen.

Comment: @John Anderson I need your help

Comment: Seems you want to capture whole view/frame apart from the default function `print`. One option is using [`export_to_png`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.export_to_png) on the desired widget.

Comment: @ApuCoder You mean the print() can do this? Could you please explain more on this? How do I use the export to png?

Comment: Thanks a lot AnuCoder. The export_to_PNG works fine. It actually just saves it on my system

Comment: Can you add the code you wrote?

Comment: @JerodG I exported the boxlayout that house the items I want to print using the following code. self.ids.sbbx.export_to_png("c:/Users/hp/Desktop/myapp.png")  then I used the os module to execute print job on the exported file using this os.startfile("c:/Users/hp/Desktop/myapp.png", "print")